# Is a lockscreen a deterrent to a USB Rubber Ducky style of attack?

Tags: linux, usb

Lets say we are on the Linux platform and usb is authorized to work by default.

From what I understand USB Rubber Ducky acts as a keyboard and tries to type in bash commands right?

But what if the screen is locked, how does it bypass that? I mean if you plugin a physical keyboard you clearly need to type in the right passphrase to be able to do anything useful.

Perhaps I have the wrong concept of how a Rubber Ducky attack works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you understand it correctly. USB Rubber Ducky cannot bypass the login screen or the lock screen (in a way other than providing the correct password).

It can contain payload brute-forcing the password for the user, but it cannot bypass it otherwise.